# How to set a URL parameter and set the value of a select option on page load based on the URL parameter

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a select dropdown that is populated based on a database table. I want to use a query string parameter in the url that automatically selects an option in the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-xl-7">
    <select name="autoMessageTemplates" id="autoMessageTemplates" class="form-select" @onchange="FindMessageTemplateAndSendToParent">
        <option></option>
        @foreach (var template in messageTemplates ?? Enumerable.Empty<MessageTemplateDto>())
        {
            <option>@template.TemplateKey</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm new to using url parameters and all of the examples I have found are in jquery or in php. So how would I use a url parameter to have a dropdown option selected based on it in blazor?

Edit:

I have tried to find a solution and have come up with the below but it doesn't work. Can some suggest an edit to kae it work or a different solution entirely is welcome.

```
<div class="col-xl-7">
    <select name="autoMessageTemplates" id="autoMessageTemplates" class="form-select" @onchange="FindMessageTemplateAndSendToParent">
        <option></option>
        @foreach (var template in messageTemplates ?? Enumerable.Empty<MessageTemplateDto>())
        {
            <option selected="@(template.Id == messageTemplateId) ? selected : ''">@template.TemplateKey</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#query-strings)

Comment: Clarifying... You want the URL to preselect an option in a `select`. When you change the 
 selection you want to update the URL or Navigate? This all happens in a sub-component on the page??

Comment: The url should preselect an option in the select.